# Angularjs: conditionally chain filters?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I want to create an array off an existing array by applying up to 3 filters.

Is it possible to conditionally chain filters, something as follows?

```
<div ng-init="questions =  (quizz.questions | f1&&filter:{f1:f1} | f2&&filter:{f:f2} |f3&&filter:{f: f3} )"></div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why don't you put this logic, which looks complex, into the controller?

Comment: I could. That's my fallback if no solutions are found.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you are conditionally combining multiple custom filters? You could pass in a parameter to each of the filters, indicating whether it should actually filter results or just return the input array.

For example:

```
<div ng-init="questions = (quizz.questions | filter:f1 | filter:f2 | filter:f3 )"></div>
```

where `f1`/`f2`/`f3` control whether the filter should be applied or not (sorry, not quite sure of your desired logic). The filter might look like this:

```
.filter('filter', function (input, apply) {

    if (!apply) {
        return input;
    }

    ...
});
```